# Error al instalar un plugin con Ionic Cordova

Tags: ionic, cordova, ionic-framework

Estoy intentando instalar un plugin con Ionic Cordova **InAppBrowser**, cuando intento utilizar este comando

**ionic cordova plugin add @ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser**

Me aparece esto

```
npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 '@ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Esto me aparece cuando ejecuto el comando con el --verbose

```
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +4ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 19128: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 19128 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "19128".
  ionic:utils-process
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 19128 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +421ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 19128 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "19128".
  ionic:utils-process
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 19128 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +24ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +5ms
```

Tengo la version de Ionic 4.6.2 y la version de Cordova de 9.0.0

Answer (score 0):

-- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
-- npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!